# How to close implicit Stream in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, try-with-resources

Files.walk is one of the streams that I should close, however, how do I close the stream in code like below? Is the code below valid or do I need to rewrite it so I have access to the stream to close it?

```
List<Path> filesList = Files.walk(Paths.get(path)).filter(Files::isRegularFile ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use it with try-with-resource as:

```
try(Stream<Path> path = Files.walk(Paths.get(""))) {
    List<Path> fileList = path.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The `apiNote` for the **[`Files.walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...))** explicitly reads this :

> ```
> This method must be used within a try-with-resources statement or similar
> control structure to ensure that the stream's open directories are closed
> promptly after the stream's operations have completed.
> ```

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer. I was hoping that Java provided a better way like automatically closing implicit streams since they are not accessible anymore.

Comment: @CJ there’s no such thing like an “implicit stream”. It’s the way you use the `Files.walk` method which makes the stream instance inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Files.walk method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-):

> The returned stream encapsulates one or more DirectoryStreams. If
>   timely disposal of file system resources is required, **the
>   try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the
>   stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are
>   completed.** Operating on a closed stream will result in an
>   IllegalStateException.

Emphasis mine.